# SQL SHOW one more column name FROM operator in

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to show columns from  IN
 operator
My query is :

```
    SELECT prizes.type,prizes.name
       FROM  lottery_payment_prizes payment
         JOIN lottery_prizes prizes ON 
          prizes.id =  payment.prize_id 
     WHERE payment.payment_id IN
       (( SELECT id FROM lottery_payments 
      WHERE  lottery_id = (SELECT id FROM lotteries WHERE abbr = 'TR' AND group_id = '3' )))
```

Result is:[image]

My question : How can show two columns from lottery_payments ,
lottery_payments   returns only ID to IN  operator

function.
I need to show column name "place" from lottery_payemnts table.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to columns from `lottery_payments`, you need to add a join to it:

```
SELECT payments.place, payments.id, prizes.type, prizes.name
   FROM  lottery_payment_prizes payment
     JOIN lottery_prizes prizes ON 
      prizes.id =  payment.prize_id 
     JOIN lottery_payments payments ON 
      payment.payment_id =  payments.id 
 WHERE lottery_id = (SELECT id FROM lotteries WHERE abbr = 'TR' AND group_id = '3' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using IN You should use join

```
SELECT prizes.type,prizes.name
  FROM 
   lottery_payment_prizes payment
 JOIN 
   lottery_prizes prizes ON prizes.id =  payment.prize_id 
 JOIN lottery_payments lp ON payment.payment_id = lp.id
  WHERE  lp.lottery_id = (SELECT id FROM lotteries WHERE abbr = 'TR' AND group_id = '3' )))
```